# Optimizing logistic regression with a custom penalty using gradient descent

Tags: regression, logistic, regularization, loss-functions, gradient-descent

I'm trying to fit a logistic regression model on a certain dataset. I want to ensure the learned model is smooth, that is samples which belong to the same cluster/group according to a prior knowledge/graph get similar output. I'm also looking for a model with a sparse coefficients. Hence I have come up with the following loss function that takes into account the above requirements:

$$
\mathfrak{L(\mathbf{\beta })} = \underbrace{-\sum_{i=1}^{m}y_{i}\beta^{T}x_{i} + \log{(1 + e^{\beta^{T}x_{i}})}}_{logloss} \ + \ \lambda_{1}\left\|\beta \right\|_{1} + \lambda_{2}f^{T}Lf
$$

In above equation, the smoothness penalty is the $f^{T}Lf$ term, whereas $\lambda_{1}$ and $\lambda_{2}$ are regularization terms. $L$ is a Laplacian matrix of the graph formed from the samples and $ f = sigmoid(\mathbf{\beta}^{T}\mathbf{X})$. If the loss function was made up of only the log loss and the smoothness penalty, I can easily use gradient descent to optimize it since these functions are convex functions (because $L$ is positive definite matrix). But with the addition of the L1 penalty ($\left\|\beta \right\|_{1}$), the whole loss funciton can not be optimized using gradient optimization as $\left\|\beta \right\|_{1}$ is not a smooth function.

How can I use gradient descent in this case? or are there any alternative suggestions to optimize the above loss function?

Comment: Compare with elastic net.

Comment: Adding the $\lVert \beta \rVert_1$ term maintains convexity, no? Since the $\ell_1$ penalty still has a well-defined *subgradient,* this should still converge with subgradient descent (same as gradient descent, except at $\beta = 0$) given appropriate initialization and learning rate schedule.

Comment: See [this example](https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee364b/lectures/subgradients_slides.pdf) of the subgradient for $f(x) = |x|$, slide 6; [this](https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee364b/lectures/subgrad_method_slides.pdf) provides a primer on subgradient methods, which should look familiar if you've seen standard gradient descent.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I was able to find a solution as explained in my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the methodology in this [paper](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/2020408.2020421) where they improve upon GLMNET to solve L1 regularized logistic regression. Since $f^{T}Lf$ is twice differentiable, I added its gradient and hessian to the solution in equation 11 of the paper. Someone has already implemented the code for the paper [here](https://github.com/dallascard/lrb) which I've built upon. You can find my changes [here](https://github.com/Habush/lrb)